# Re-assigning a singleton class to a subclass in Swift

Tags: swift, class, singleton

In Swift, I have a Skin class that is defined as an ObservableObject singleton with:

```
class Skin: ObservableObject {
   @ObservedObject var theCurrentWorld = WorldViewController.shared

   static var shared = Skin()
   
   @Published var skinName = "Default Skin”
…gobs of other properties
```

I access that from all over my app using

```
@ObservedObject var currentSkin = Skin.shared
```

I also have subclasses of skins that override some properties and methods of the basic Skin class. When the user decides to change skins, I would like to be able to reassign currentSkin to be one of these subclasses.

But if I say

```
currentSkin = LeopardSkin()
```

I get: `Cannot assign to property: 'self' is immutable`

If, instead, I say:

```
currentSkin.shared = LeopardSkin()
```

I get:

`Static member 'shared' cannot be used on instance of type 'Skin'`

So then if I just say:

```
Skin.shared = LeopardSkin()
```

It compiles but currentSkin is still the original, base Skin. I know this from examining some properties and tracing some methods.

So now I'm out of ideas. Any help would be great!

Comment: There is so much missing but there is likely an observation issue it is obvious you are new to SwiftUI because you are misuing `ObservedObject`, it only works in a `View` you cannot observe it in a class with SwiftUI wrappers. You can tap into `Combine` and use `sink`

Comment: To understand how to manage data in your SwiftUI app, have a look at this  **official** link, it gives you some good examples of how to manage data in your app:  [monitoring data](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/monitoring-model-data-changes-in-your-app) . Also checkout, 

[ObservableObject](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/Combine/ObservableObject)  You can see from the first link ,that `ObservableObject` and `singleton pattern` are not used together.